# SOS polynomial with Drake and Mosek yields error code 1501

Tags: drake

I am trying to solve a MathematicalProgram with an SOSPolynomial. I am running Drake in C++ compiled from source with Mosek.

The MathematicalProgram contains a quadratic cost function and some equality constraints, which works fine when calling `Solve()` without adding the SOS polynomials. When looking at `result.get_solver_id()`, I find: "Equality constrained QP", as expected.

However, upon calling `Solve()`, after adding an SOS polynomial through `prog.NewSosPolynomial({t}, degree)` (with `t` being a decision variable) the program returns that a solution could not be found. When looking at the value found in `result_.get_solution_result()`, I find `solution_status = false` and `rescode = 1501`.

Looking [here](https://docs.mosek.com/9.0/capi/response-codes.html), `rescode = 1501` means: "The problem contains nonlinear terms conic constraints. The requested operation cannot be applied to this type of problem.". However, by checking the value of `result.get_solver_id()` before adding the SOS Polynomial, it is clear that there are no other nonlinear constraints in the problem.

Am I missing something here, or is this a bug?

Comment: When you add the constraint `prog.NewSosPolynomial({t}, degree)`, you mentioned that `t` is a decision variable. But SOS polynomial would require `t` being indeterminates (declared through prog.NewIndeterminates). The decision variables are the coefficients in this SOS polynomial, not `t`.

Comment: Yes I agree, t is actually declared as an indeterminate variable and not a decision variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  The standard form for a semi-definite program (which results from our SOS constraint) only accepts linear objectives, not quadratic objectives.  This does not result in any loss of generality, because you can use a slack variable.  Can you try the following:

Right now you have something like

```
min x'Qx
s.t. Ax=b, p(t) is SOS.
```

Can you write it instead as

```
min a
s.t. Ax=b, p(t) is SOS, x'Qx <= a
```

but add the `x'Qx <= a` using [`AddLorenzConeConstraint`](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1solvers_1_1_mathematical_program.html#a3289379ea86c27fb1d76262f755a00c6)?  (Note: looks like you might actually use `x'Qx <= a^2` and `a >= 0`).

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! Now Mosek solves the QP with SOS polynomials without any problems. Is this a bug in the way the SOS constraints are formulated as a SDP program behind the scenes?

One more thing: now I tried to solve the program with both SOS constraints and mixed integers in the same program, which resultet in the rescode 1503: "The global optimizer can only be applied to problems without semidefinite variables." My guess is that MISOS  programs are not supported by Mosek, and that I have to reformulate the problem as a MISOCP program. Is this correct?

Comment: A SOS constraint is imposed as an SDP problem. An SDP in the standard form accepts only linear cost. Hence you will need to convert the quadratic cost to linear cost with slack variables and second order cone constraint, as Russ mentioned.

Comment: To you MISOS problem, currently Mosek 9 doesn't support MISOS or MISDP. It does support MISOCP.

In order to convert SOS to SOCP, you can consider two approaches, first if your SDP is on a 2 x 2 matrix, then this matrix being positive semidefinite is actually a second order cone constraint. The second approach is to use an second order cone as an inner approximation of the positive semidefinite constraint (namely use sdsos instead of sos). You could call `prog.NewNonnegativePolynomial({t}, degree, NonnegativePolynomial::kSdsos)` to create sdsos.

Comment: I see, thanks! Could you point me in a direction where I might find an approach for converting a 2x2 SDP matrix to a SOCP? I thought I solved it, but I’m still having some issues with my program.

Comment: If you have a 2 x 2 matrix
[a b; b c]
being positive semidefinite, this is equivalent to the following condition
a >= 0, c >= 0, ac >= b^2
which is a rotated Lorentz cone constraint. You could add this constraint using `prog.AddRotatedLorentzConeConstraint` (for example https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1solvers_1_1_mathematical_program.html#a12a0bbb8698b6c9015f06ef81f29e472 or its overloaded functions).

If your psd matrix is not 2 x 2, then I recommend using the SDSOS approach mentioned above.

Comment: BTW, now in drake, when you call Mosek with a quadratic cost and SOS constraint, it automatically convert the quadratic cost to a linear cost with Lorentz cone constraint, so you won't receive that error 1501. This is resolved in the PR https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/14237